# Get wp slider list from wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

how I query from database for all slider list which I created with WP-Slider plugin ?
and in which database table this plugin srore?

Comment: `select * from wp_posts where post_type = 'Slider'`

Comment: Hi, its give empty record. but I had created 4 slider from dashboard. I am using this slider plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-slider-ssp/ . i want to get all slider name from database query but i dont find in which table its installed. thanks for reply.

Comment: anyone please help me out..

Comment: Look at line 84 of the file `/includes/classes/ssp_slider_post_type`, where it tells you what the post type value is...then look in your database at the wp_posts table and find the post_Type column that matches slider, then find out where the query went wrong. beyond this, no one will be able to help.